# Is there a way to choose route animation with a method that wraps router.navigate()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'd like to be able to choose the route animation by calling a particular method.

If there is another way to do it, please feel free to share.

Lets say I create/provide a service class called "AnimatedRouter", it contains methods that use Angular's router but trigger a different animation based on the method I run.

eg:

```
   import { Router } from "@angular/router"

   exports class AnimatedRouter {
          constructor(private router:Router){} 

          fade(route:Array){
                 this.router.navigate(route) //somehow with fade animation
          }

          slideIn(route:Array){
                 this.router.navigate(route) //somehow with slide animation
          }
   }
```

Then to use it:

```
   import { AnimatedRouter } from "../services/animated-router.service"

   exports class Thing {
          constructor(private animatedRouter:AnimatedRouter){} 

          trigger(){
                 //do stuff
                 this.animatedRouter.fade(['my', 'new', 'route'])      
          }
   }
```

I haven't been unable to find any resources that help me find out how to do this - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to do it centrally?

Comment: It makes sense to me to do it centrally, that way I can choose what animation I want to have coming into a route - but if you have another suggestion, I'm open to it.

-- EDIT: Additionally, Is there also a way to have the leave animation set by the same method? 

- So if I fadein into a route, if I push back it will fadeout otherwise I can specify an animation for the next route overriding the exit animation?